# Rails: routing and path helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails: Routing without plurals gives strange helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730057/rails-routing-without-plurals-gives-strange-helpers)

Turns out I had :resources qtl_table in config/routes.rb twice! I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `search_qtl_table_index' for #<#<Class:0x805aff3e0>:0x805af47b0>
```

in app/views/qtl_table/index.html.erb:

```
<h2>Search for QTL</h2>
<%= form_tag search_qtl_table_index, :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

and in config/routes.rb:

```
Qtl::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :qtl_table do
            collection do
                    get 'search'
            end
    end
  ...
end
```

yes I do have plurals turned off:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

Output of rake routes:

```
              search_qtl_table_index GET    /qtl_table/search(.:format)                            {:action=>"search", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                     qtl_table_index GET    /qtl_table(.:format)                                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                                     POST   /qtl_table(.:format)                                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                       new_qtl_table GET    /qtl_table/new(.:format)                               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                      edit_qtl_table GET    /qtl_table/:id/edit(.:format)                          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                           qtl_table GET    /qtl_table/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                                     PUT    /qtl_table/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                                     DELETE /qtl_table/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
```

Comment: Step #1: What is the output of `rake routes` relevant to that defined route?

Comment: Please refrain from reposting your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have plurals turned off, but this only affects the table names in the database, not how Rails handles routes.

Because the `search` route belongs to a *collection*, not a member, it acts on multiple model objects. Therefore, the route should be `search_qtl_tables_path`, note plural tables.

`qtl_table` is a model, and you want to search a collection of them, so it make senses that the route reads like "search multiple records".

**edit**: My main concern is that your `rake routes` shouldn't be showing those qtl_table routes twice. Are you repeating yourself somewhere in `routes.rb`?

OK, so you've deleted the extra routes. Now, this should work...

```
<%= form_tag search_qtl_table_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

Comment: search_qtl_tables_path also did not work :(

Comment: Weird, [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) say that's the expected behaviour. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Turns out I had :resources qtl_table in config/routes.rb twice! Still getting error and rake routes has a strange helper for my search method. ANy ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer. Notice the extra `_path` at the end of the method call.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Qtl::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :qtl_table do
        collection do
                get 'search', :as => 'search_qtl_table'
        end
    end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Didn't work :( any other suggestions

Comment: Did you used `form_tag search_qtl_table_path, :method => 'get'` ?