# Rails: Routing without plurals gives strange helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, helper

I am getting a strange named helpers with this setup:

In config/routes.rb I have:

```
Qtl::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :qtl_table do
            collection do
                    get 'search'
            end
    end
...
end
```

rake routes outputs this:

```
              search_qtl_table_index GET    /qtl_table/search(.:format)                            {:action=>"search", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                     qtl_table_index GET    /qtl_table(.:format)                                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                                     POST   /qtl_table(.:format)                                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                       new_qtl_table GET    /qtl_table/new(.:format)                               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                      edit_qtl_table GET    /qtl_table/:id/edit(.:format)                          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                           qtl_table GET    /qtl_table/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                                     PUT    /qtl_table/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
                                     DELETE /qtl_table/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"qtl_table"}
```

and I do have plurals turned off:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

but I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `search_qtl_table_index' for #<#<Class:0x8056a3fa8>:0x8056a2338>
```

This is related to this question which I will delete soon:
[Rails: routing and path helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729125/rails-routing-and-path-helpers/8729194#8729194)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pluralizing. YOu need to use `search_qtl_table_index_path` when you reference it rather than just `search_qtl_table_index` (you need to add the `_path` to the end).

So, your `form_tag` statement should be:

```
<%= form_tag search_qtl_table_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```